# Как добавить фоновую музыку в Android - игру, которая не будет играть при сворачивании и блокировке экрана

Tags: java, android, музыка

У меня есть игра с несколькими активити. Мне нужно добавить на фон музыку, которая не будет останавливаться при переходе между активити, но она должна останавливаться когда приложение сворачивается и когда экран блокируется. Пробовал Service, но как оказалось это не то что мне нужно.